# Should a player use the provided carbon copy sheet to record moves in a club/tournament?

Tags: rules, fide, notation

I've been told some times that I must record my moves in the carbon copy sheet provided by the organizer instead of using my own chess notebooks.
Is there any rule preventing me from using my own record sheets?

Comment: The questions are not duplicates. The other is about scorebooks with room for annotating many games which **sometimes are allowed and sold in tournaments**, and targets article 11.3.1 (the use of sources of information). This question is about the use of a player's own paper (even if empty) and targets article 8.1.1.

Comment: The 8.1.1. rule did, however, also come up in relation to the scorebook question, as one may argue that the requirement to record the moves "on the scoresheet prescribed for the competition" in effect prohibits recodring of moves on any scoresheet that was not prescribed for the competition.

Comment: @acye Granted, but that doesn't mean the two questions are equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the rules:

8.1.1 In the course of play each player is required to record his own moves and those of his opponent in the correct manner, move after move, as clearly and legibly as possible, in the algebraic notation (Appendix C), **on the ‘scoresheet’ prescribed for the competition**.

And also important:

8.3 The scoresheets are the property of the organiser of the competition.